# Declaring an object as a function but with child functions

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

It's not hard to figure out how to declare an object as a callable function:

```
const Sys = {
  log: function() {
    //do whatever
  }
}
```

and then call it with `Sys.log();`

But how would I go about maintaining this functionality while adding new children functions?

Basically, I want to be able to call something like `Sys.log.clear()` while still being able to call `Sys.log()`.

The closest I've gotten is this, but it obviously doesn't work or I wouldn't be asking here  ¯_(ツ)_/¯ Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
const Sys = {
  log: {
    function(arg) {
      alert(arg);
    },
    clear: function(arg) {
      alert(arg);
    }
 }
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kqbqzvur/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I think it's going to be hard to do this cleanly in an object literal. You could define a function that returns the function you want:

```js
function makelog() {
    let fn = function(arg){
        console.log(arg)
    }
    fn.clear = function(arg){
        console.log(arg)
    }
    return fn
}

const sys = {
    log: makelog()
}

sys.log("hello")
sys.log.clear("world")
```

This is about the same as:

```js
const sys = {
  log: function(arg) {
    console.log(arg)
  }
}
sys.log.clear = function(arg) {
  console.log(arg)
}

sys.log("hello")
sys.log.clear("world")
```

If you can use getters, you could do something like this too:

```js
const sys = {
    get log() {
            let fn = function(arg){
                console.log("from log: ", arg)
            }
            fn.clear = function(arg){
                console.log("from clear: ", arg)
            }
            return fn
        }
    }

sys.log("foo")
sys.log.clear("bar")
```

You can also return your object from a function which allows a more traditional chaining, but then you need to call both functions:

```js
const sys = {
    log: function(arg) {
            if (arg !== undefined) console.log(arg);
            return this
        },
    clear: function(arg) {
        console.log(arg);
    }
 
  }

sys.log("hello").clear("world")
sys.log("just log")
sys.log().clear("just clear")
```

Comment: For bonus points, with the Object method chaining method at the bottom, how would I take information passed into `log('')` and hand it off to `clear()` without cluttering the global scope?

Comment: Perhaps I should open a new question for that, there doesn't seem to be an answer anywhere.

Comment: Hi @Arlo - I think that will be tough to do directly because they are really two independent function calls. One thing you might get away with is storing a value on `this` during `log()` and then referencing during `clear()`. Not sure of another way.